# Creating AWS Distribution With Default Viewer Certificate Results in InvalidViewerCertificate

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to create new AWS Distribution via API, where I am setting:

```
    "ViewerCertificate": {
        "CloudFrontDefaultCertificate": true
    },
```

This should use the default CF certificate, but as a result I am getting this error:

```
InvalidViewerCertificate
To add an alternate domain name (CNAME) to a CloudFront distribution, you must attach a trusted certificate that validates your authorization to use the domain name.

{
"DistributionConfig": {
    "Aliases": {
        "Quantity": 2,
        "Items": ["www.xxyz.com", "xyz.com"]
    },
    "DefaultRootObject": "",
    "Origins": {
        "Quantity": 1,
        "Items": [{
            "Id": "RJMn5FUTvrqoh-cloudfrontxyz.com",
            "DomainName": "chzsgor80ynsme.xyz.com",
            "OriginPath": "",
            "CustomHeaders": {
                "Quantity": 0
            },
            "CustomOriginConfig": {
                "HTTPPort": 80,
                "HTTPSPort": 443,
                "OriginProtocolPolicy": "http-only",
                "OriginSslProtocols": {
                    "Quantity": 4,
                    "Items": ["SSLv3", "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"]
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    "DefaultCacheBehavior": {
        "TargetOriginId": "RJMn5FUTvrqoh-cloudfrontxyz.com",
        "ForwardedValues": {
            "QueryString": true,
            "Cookies": {
                "Forward": "all"
            },
            "Headers": {
                "Quantity": 1,
                "Items": ["Host"]
            }
        },
        "TrustedSigners": {
            "Enabled": false,
            "Quantity": 0
        },
        "ViewerProtocolPolicy": "allow-all",
        "AllowedMethods": {
            "Quantity": 7,
            "Items": ["HEAD", "DELETE", "POST", "GET", "OPTIONS", "PUT", "PATCH"],
            "CachedMethods": {
                "Quantity": 2,
                "Items": ["HEAD", "GET"]
            }
        },
        "SmoothStreaming": false,
        "MinTTL": 0,
        "DefaultTTL": 3600,
        "MaxTTL": 31536000,
        "Compress": false
    },
    "CacheBehaviors": {
        "Quantity": 0
    },
    "CustomErrorResponses": {
        "Quantity": 0
    },
    "Comment": "",
    "Logging": {
        "Enabled": false,
        "Bucket": "",
        "Prefix": "",
        "IncludeCookies": true
    },
    "Enabled": true,
    "PriceClass": "PriceClass_100",
    "ViewerCertificate": {
        "CloudFrontDefaultCertificate": true
    },
    "Restrictions": {
        "GeoRestriction": {
            "RestrictionType": "none",
            "Quantity": 0
        }
    },
    "WebACLId": "",
    "CallerReference": "xyz-1555690298"
}
```

}

This actually worked few weeks ago, but something probably changed.
Or, maybe there is a limitation to the amount of distributions allowed with a default certificate?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because of CloudFront recent announcement:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=6725

Since you're adding the CNAME:
"Aliases": {
"Quantity": 2,
"Items": ["www.xxyz.com", "xyz.com"]
}